# Implement a static website into play

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am a beginner with the `playframework`. My first goal is to just implement a static `html, css, javascript` website into play and then later add some forms ect.

I tried to just paste the code into:

`index.scala.html && main.scala.html`

My routing File looks like that:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                       controllers.Application.index()
```

My Controller looks like that:

package controllers;

```
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return TODO;
    }

}
```

However, I get:

[image]

What should I change to `just` display a HTML page?

I appreciate your answer!

PS.: I am using `play 2.2.1`

**UPDATE**

I tried it now with:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        ok(index.render());
    }

}
```

However I get an error:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should go through a tutorial and learn some of the basics in Play. There is one in the play docs: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTodoList

Comment: @johanandren Yes I had a look at this application however, they are doing it as I described in my `Update`. However that does not work for me...

Comment: you are requesting `/tasks` in the first picture. did you define it in the routes file? to the compiliation error: check if you have the `index` file in the views directory. furthermore, if you are using the default index template, you might need to pass a string to the index function `ok(index.render("hello world"));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you returning TODO? Make it return `ok(index.render());` if you want to show your index-template.

Comment: THX a lot for your answer! However, I get an error in eclipse `index cannot be resolved`...

Comment: Eclipse won't see it until it's been compiled to a class and you've refreshed the project etc. etc., so I'd advise you to ignore eclipse's error messages regarding the templates.

Comment: THX for your answer! Pls also see my update... However, even after cleaning my project and also after just doing `play run` it does not work...

Comment: Well, if your template files are pure HTML, it's probably going to fail. They're supposed to be compilable scala template files. You should definitely work on the tutorials, they have all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use assets for static content.

In the conf/routes, you make a generic mapping like this:

```
GET  /assets/*file        Assets.at("public", file)
```

Now all requests that start with /assets/ will be mapped to files of the same name in the public subdir. This will even work for deeper nesting, like /assets/javascript/myapp.js

Answer (score 1):

You have removed the return, the syntax is

```
public static Result index() {
    return ok(index.render());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your imports as below

```
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.*;
```

This would work for the below snippet 
ok(index.render());